# Motivation for Abstract Nonsingular Curves

Tags: algebraic-geometry, motivation

I just got through reading section I.6 in Hartshorne, and I have no idea why anybody would ever have invented these concepts. I agree that what you can do with it is pretty neat, but how would anyone have ever thought of it?

In case anyone needs the definitions, here they are.

If $K$ is a function field of dimension $1$ and $k$ is a subfield of $K$ such that the valuation function $v$ satisfies $v(x) = 0$ for all $ x \in k- \{0\}$, then $v$ is a valuation of $K/k$ and $R := \{ x \in K| v(x) \geq 0 \}$ is a valuation ring of $K/k$. Given a particular $K$, define $C_K$ to be the set of all discrete valuation rings of $K/k$. Topologize $C_K$ by declaring the closed sets to be the finite subsets, and $C_K$ itself. Now an abstract non-singular curve is an open subset.

These things do have a handful of really nice theorems Hartshorne proves in the section, but I would never have thought to look at such objects. In fact it feels completely unmotivated.

So my question is either a) how would you think this up, or b) can we prove the main theorem of this section, which is that every curve is birational to a non-singular projective curve, without all of this?

Comment: One way that you can prove the stated result is through normalization. See the excellent answer at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/51144/abstract-nonsingular-curves .

Comment: My suggestion is to first, before Hartshorne, read volume 1 of Shafarevich's book (much more geometric), if you are looking for a motivation.

Comment: I have read Shafarevich's volume 1, but I don't recall seeing anything like this in it. It was useful intuition in general.

Comment: About b): the main Theorem of this section is that every abstract nonsingular curve is birational to a nonsingular projective curve. Of course, you cannot prove such a theorem without defining what an abstract nonsingular curve is. If you want to prove, for example, that every quasiprojective curve is birational to a nonsingular projective curve, then as @KReiser suggests you can do that via normalization (or numerous other methods --- for example see Chapter 1 of _Lectures on Resolution of Singularities_ by Koll\'ar. But this is _a priori_ weaker than what is proved in Hartshorne).

Comment: About a): that is a good question but hard to answer. I think the short answer is that algebraic geometers of the late 19th century understood very well that birational varieties have isomorphic function fields, and that nonsingular projective curves that are birational are in fact isomorphic. So if you want to give an _intrinsic_ definition of a nonsingular curve, it is enough to specify a field together with a cofinite set of its discrete valuations, etc. My recollection is that Dedekind and Weber came up with this idea in their 1882 paper in order to develop the theory of Riemann surfaces..

Comment: in a purely algebraic way. For an accurate historical account of this development (and many others) there is the excellent _History of Algebraic Geometry_ by Dieudonn\'e.